# angular ui-sortable not updating model of filtered list

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui, angularjs-filter, angular-ui-sortable

I have been digging SO and other posts but couldn't make it work. I have a list which i iterate with ng-repeat and apply some filters over it. Ui-sortable works well when the index of the list is not altered but as soon as the index is altered (by filters), the filtered list doesn't reflect the sorted order.
Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hKYWr/1996/

```
<div ng:controller="controller">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="query" placeholder="Search...">
    <div ui:sortable ng:model="filteredList">
        <div ng:repeat="item in filteredList = (list | filter:query | limitTo:4)" class="item">{{item.val}}</div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div ng:repeat="item in filteredList">{{item.val}}</div>
</div>

<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.js"></script>`

var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui']);
myapp.controller('controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.list = [{val:"one",count:1}, {val:"two",count:2}, {val:"three",count:3},{val:"four",count:4}];
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp']);
```

I want my filteredList to get updated as soon as i do the sorting. Any help?